# Does $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ admits infinitely many densely defined derivations in weak* topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

To clarify the question. First we define what is densely defined derivation. A densely defined derivation $\delta:D(\delta):\rightarrow L^{\infty}[0,1]$ where $D(\delta)$ is a dense subalgebra( in weak* topology).
According to what I know, $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is *-isomorphic to $L^{\infty}([0,1]^{n})$ for any natural number n. According to what I know, $C^{\infty}([0,1]^{n})$ is weakly * dense in $L^{\infty}([0,1]^{n})$, does that mean $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ have at least n densely defined derivations for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence infinite? Is there any consequences of this result(If the above deduction is correct)?

Comment: Everything you said is true, and, I think, well-known.

Comment: Thanks, at least I got that right.